# Why isn't this printing 5 items at a time?

Tags: c++

```
void diplayNames(name array[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << array[i].num << "." << array[i].name << endl;
    }

    cout << "Press ENTER to see the last five names" << endl;
    cin.ignore();

    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << array[i].num << "." << array[i].name << endl;
    }
}
```

Why isn't this printing 5 names at once, then asking for the user to hit enter and print the last 5 names? It prints all 10 names at once and between name 4 and 5 it prints the "Press ENTER to see the last five names".

I've tried adding `if(i % 5 ==0)` under the `for` loop and above the `cout`.

Comment: try `for (int i = size-5; i < size; i++)`

Comment: I want to call names and corresponding numbers I have in a structure array. I would like to have the display function print 5 names, then after the user selects 'Enter" it prints the next 5 names and numbers.

Comment: That's right: it doesn't read a line (it doesn't wait for ENTER) because you're _not_ telling it to read a line. You're missing a cin.getline(). The cin.ignore() _may_ be used before that one, when you need to clean the input buffer.

Comment: You can also use something like `cin >> dummyStringBuffer` in place of `cin.getline()`.

Comment: `cin.ignore()` does not cause the program to pause and wait for input.   It extracts and discards characters from the stream buffer *if already present*.

Comment: The correct way to make `ignore()` wait for ENTER is `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`, provided ENTER (`'\n'`) is not already in the input buffer.

Answer (score 2):

We assume that the program read some input earlier, like names. We also assume that this input was terminated by pressing Enter.

Then this Enter is still in the input buffer, just waiting for `ignore()`to read it (and throw it away). It isn't waiting for new input, as there already is some.